# How to dynamically remove keys from a typed object in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

How can I dynamically remove keys from a typed object?

For example, my interface `QUERY_PARAMS` is:

```
export interface QUERY_PARAMS {
  query: string;
  min_height?: string;
  max_height?: string;
  min_width?: string;
  max_width?: string;
  color?: string;
  image_type?: IMAGETYPE;
  order?: ORDER;
  orientation?: ORIENTATION;
}
```

My code for trying to dynamically delete keys:

```
  async getAllImages(inputParams: QUERY_PARAMS) {
     for (let key in inputParams) {
       if (!inputParams[key]) {
         delete inputParams[key]
       }
     }
     // ...
  }
```

It throws the error:

> element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'QUERY_PARAMS'.
> No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'QUERY_PARAMS'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because `key` is a string, which isn't specific enough to be an attribute of `inputParams`, i.e. `keyof QUERY_PARAMS`. Currently TS doesn't allow you to define a type for the iteration variable of a `for` loop ([issue#3500](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3500)), but you can do a type-assertion on the key inside the loop:

```
export interface QUERY_PARAMS {
  query: string;
  min_height?: string;
  // ...
}

async function getAllImages(inputParams: QUERY_PARAMS) {
  for (let key in inputParams) {
    const k = key as keyof QUERY_PARAMS; // <-- type assertion
    if (!inputParams[k]) {
      delete inputParams[k]
    }
  }

  // ...
}

const p: QUERY_PARAMS = {
  query: 's',
  min_height: undefined,
}

console.log(p); // { query: 's', min_height: undefined }

getAllImages(p);

console.log(p); // { query: 's' }
```